# UITableViewCell drawRect() Override Makes Device Really Slow (CPU Usage Spike)

Tags: swift, uitableview, drawrect, cgrect

That's pretty much my issue. I want to create rounded plain cells in a table view. I override `drawRect(frame: CGRect)` in a `TableViewCell` class, but when the cell is shown, the device (simulator too) freezes for about 1 second and the debugger shows a spike in CPU usage to 75%.

Not that it might be of any use, but here's my code:

```
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    frame.origin.x = 10
    frame.size.width -= 20
}
```

So is there any easier/MUCH more efficient/"legal"(somebody said overriding drawRect is considered "hacky") way of simply making every cell narrower than the screen?

Comment: The actual cell's frame will be managed by the tableview, you can add your own custom subviews inside of the `cell.contentView`. Why are you using drawrect at all? worried about performance? The tableview is efficient at caching and reusing cells. Unless you are displaying 1000's of cells on the screen, you won't need to worry about the efficiency of the drawing

Comment: Yes, I noticed that the CPU spike only happens on the first cell, then afterwards it works fine. I'll try using a subview. Post it as an answer so I'll chose it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really allowed to use `drawRect` to modify a view's frame. `drawRect` just gives you an opportunity to draw within the given frame.

The actual frame of a `UITableViewCell` is managed by the `UITableView` through it's width and the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Also, the table view is very efficient at caching and reusing cells. Unless you are displaying 1000's of cell on the screen, you won't need to worry about the efficiency of the drawing.

I think you should be adding a subview to the cell's `contentView`, and  setting it's frame as inset to the cell. This can be done using autolayout in a custom cell xib, or manaully in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Thanks! I did what you said in the comment and worked great.